# Is it right way to store security fields in cookies?

Tags: security, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-identity, session-cookies

I trying to store extra fields in cookies with ASP.Net Core Identity.

one of this fields, is Role Name.

Is it safe to store role name in cookies?

For example, is it possible that user change role name from "normalUser" to "admin"?

I am using ASP.Net Core 3.1 version.

Comment: Can a user modify cookies on their machine? (The answer is of course they can, the cookie lives on their machine). So why would you put something that controls a users access level in a location that the user controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NEVER store sensitive data in cookies. As mason said in the comment, cookies can be modified meaning they can be exploited. And besides, your cookies might be in plaintext, which is even worse.

I would recommend storing such data securely in the backend.

Sessions are definitely safer than cookies since they are stored on the server side but they also can be subject to attacks (session hijacking). You'll need to properly configure them for better security.

Comment: tnx marvan., i am with you about cookies.but now why don`t sessions??? that store in server and user don`t access to that.

Comment: Now the sessions are indeed safer than cookies since the client can't modify them and are stored on the server side. Although they are not 100% secure since an attacker can perform something called "session hijacking" (more on that in https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Session_hijacking_attack).